# Send param from client datatable to django server code

Tags: django, datatable

I am working with plugin datatable and django.

I have url to view ajax_table in urls.py:

```
url(r'^someurl/$', 'someapp.views.ajax_table', name='ajax_table'),
```

This way I can call function ajax_table from my datatable.

```
var datatable = $("#my_table").dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI" : true,
    "bProcessing":true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "{% url ajax_table %}",
    "sPaginationType": "custompagination"
};
```

It is working properly.

But when I try to send some params from client to server code:

```
"sAjaxSource": "{% url ajax_table %}?param=some_number"
```

I can not get this param on server side ('no param' printed):

```
def ajax_table(request):
    print 'param: %s' % request.GET.get('param','no param')
```

How can I send param to server properly?

Comment: can you check on firebug whether the requested url: "/someurl/?param=some_number" return anything or not

Comment: I checked it in address line - it works without adding "{% url ajax_table %}?param=some_number" to js code. Thanks.

Comment: But it is not working in code :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a django problem (you're doing the right thing here as far as django is concerned), it's a datatables issue. You can't add params directly to the `sAjaxSource` parameter, you have to do it with the datatables API.

The [following documentation](http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html) describes how to send extra data to the server in the form of parameters.

Comment: yes, you can. Datatable will take whatever url in the ajaxSource and add it owned parameters for the pagination to send back to the server

Comment: I tryed use documentation above but adding fnServerData is not helpful:                                                                def ajax_table(request): print 'name: %s' %                                                                           request.GET.get('name','no param')                                                                                                                                 This function returns 'no param', but it exists in example.

Comment: I found working example of django-datatable bundle. Documentation in link above at some place referenced to this demo. Demo has [server](https://www.assembla.com/code/datatables_demo/subversion/nodes/trunk/1_6_2/datatables_demo/demo/utils.py?rev=5) and [client](https://www.assembla.com/code/datatables_demo/subversion/nodes/trunk/1_6_2/datatables_demo/templates/demo/server_side_demo.html?rev=5) examples. This is standard way for send/receive parameters in this case.